# What does the : character mean in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: linux

I don't understand what this script is doing. What is the `:` sign within LD_LIBRARY_PATH doing?

```
#!/bin/ksh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${B%/bin/*}/lib/exec/${0##*/} "$@"
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks Shelter, but where it sets the LD_LIBRARY_PATH you see =.: what's that?

Comment: @shellter, ...well, I wouldn't describe it as the same as a comment character -- `:` evaluates to true (exit status 0), whereas a comment doesn't change `$?` at all.

Comment: I've edited this (admittedly somewhat heavy-handedly) to reflect that it's actually asking what `:` means inside `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which is honored by Linux's dynamic linker -- not part of ksh, or any other shell), not what `:` means as shell syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In LD_LIBRARY_PATH the : character is delimiter between path values.

In your situation you add current directory to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ( search path )